# How to get an average number from already counted value

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
select aa.AccNumber, aa.AccName, count(ProductID) as Products
from vProducts pr
left join vAllAccounts aa with (nolock) 
on aa.AccountID = pr.AccountID
group by  aa.AccNumber, aa.AccID, aa.AccName
order by Products desc
```

Hi, here is my query. 
I counted total numbers of products per account, but now I need to count average number of products per account using previous query.
Help me, please. I have never done this before.

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag based on the query syntax.  Sample data and desired results would help convey what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select avg(sales.Products) from
(
    select aa.AccNumber, aa.AccName, count(ProductID) as Products
    from vProducts pr
    left join vAllAccounts aa with (nolock) 
    on aa.AccountID = pr.AccountID
    group by  aa.AccNumber, aa.AccID, aa.AccName
) sales
```

Comment: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Actually, when I tried it, I noticed that result not the same as I expected.
F.E. now it looks like
number - average value (only one) for all values in table.

I need to see  aa.AccNumber, aa.AccName, count(ProductID) // and average of this value for each user

This was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the average number of products per account directly:

```
select count(pr.AccountId) * 1.0 / count(distinct aa.AccNumber)
from vAllAccounts join
     vProducts pr
     on aa.AccountID = pr.AccountID;
```

This calculates the total number of products and divides by the total number of accounts.  The `* 1.0` is because SQL Server does integer division.

If all accounts have at least one product, you can further simplify this:

```
select count(*) * 1.0 / count(distinct pr.AccNumber)
from vProducts pr;
```